# What is the best technique to sync local database from client to server in a queue

Tags: java, android, batch-processing

I am creating an offline mobile app than enable users to create content and save it locally. Content includes both text and binary files. I am looking for a library or any other techniques to sync this large volume of data, by properly handling errors and conflicts.

I already tried it by using android's [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) api, but handling conflicts and errors was painful.

Comment: How about SyncAdapter? check this link. https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually I solved this problem using the following approach. This is far more efficient in terms of error handling and speed.

[image]

A complete example of doing this could be found here,

[How to sync SQLite on Android to MySQL DB?](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/)

Comment: For the negative voter, I would like to know the reason. This is not my solution and it has been used by many of us out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can sync your content using database as a service. it would be faster and best fitted with your unstructured data. firebase is a good option for that.

https://www.firebase.com/

Comment: But i don't want to use database as a service.  We have our own server.

Comment: what kind of database you are using?

Comment: we are using SQL database.